# how can I make one of my product UNIQUE (In appearance as well as in perfromance) using a custom module

Tags: php, magento, bundle

I have a custom module for product view page and it does the exact functions that does by product view page, but for a unique product. In default product view page, a product is getting and load like this

```
<?php

    $_product=$this->getProduct();
?>
```

Since I am using my own custom module, instead of using getProduct() method, i am using

```
<?php 
     $id=44;
    /*
        this is an example id; actually $id holds required products id;
    */
     $_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id)
?>
```

I got my product details via this method. However all other functionalities such as `Add to cart`, `add to wishlist` are not working. How can I use my module in such a way that it handles all functionalities of a product view page but should apply it for only one product.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a 'productId' variable anywhere in your files? The code that you added above is not of much help to identify your issue.

Comment: do you mention about productId variable which is using in core js? 
i am using this code and button. <?php /*registering the current product*/ Mage::register('product', $_product); /* add the product object in the registry*/              
$block = Mage::getBlockSingleton('Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View'); /* Instantiate the product view block*/
 ?><button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" id="international_btn" class="btn btn-success" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)">.

Comment: i have used this script for configuration then.<script type="text/javascript">
    var bundle = new Product.Config(<?php echo $block->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>. is this the right way to set productId?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this I have used layout approach. For each product Magento generates a unique handle. I have used this property in order to achieve what I need.

Location : `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/layout/catalog.xml`

```
<PRODUCT_23>

    <!-- 
         added all layout stuffs that come under 
        `catalog_product_view` handle and changed the targeted 
         phtml file according to my need 
    -->

</PRODUCT_23>
```

That's it. Thanks